# Bind JSON to build a dynamic form in AngularJs for One-To-Many relationship and having parent-child relations in both the tables

Tags: json, angularjs, parent-child, one-to-many, dynamic-forms

I have two database tables with a one-to-many relationship between them and the parent-child relationship within each of the tables. Here **reference** table (one side) works as a master table and the **reference_copies** table (many side) works as replicas of the master.
I want to create UI form in AngularJS to provide insert/update functionalities to the user. As shown in [UI_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxRco.jpg), user can go up to the n number of level as he/she wants. Also attached the image with [database tables structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irnwr.jpg)

In **reference_copies** table, data can already exist as we are uploading through excels too. Here, name & type_id columns combining together create unique constraints. So while the user tries to add a level, I need to check if the name exists for that type or not. If exists then fetch the object else save and fetch the saved object (with created id). Here value and selected type will be the same for all levels so the user needs to select only once.

On the final submit, the master form's each level will be mapped with corresponding reference copies' each level. i.e. parent name of a master will be mapped with parent names of reference_copies 1, 2... Likewise, level1 of a master will be mapped with level1 of reference_copies 1& 2. and so on. If there is no corresponding level in either of the form, nothing happens, that level will not be mapped with any. Here, there are no restrictions to create similarity in levels. As shown in the example, the master form is having two levels, reference copy 1 form is having only one level and reference copy 2 form is having 3 levels.

On final Submit button, I want to build the json payload as below: Also when I get the response json in below format with IDs, the form should be filled as shown in above for the update.

```
    {
    "name": "Reference Name",
    "childs": [
        {
            "name": "child level1 name",
            "childs": [
                {
                    "name": "childlevel2 name",
                    "childs":[],
                    "referenceCopies": [
                        {
                            "id" : 2004
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "referenceCopies": [
                {
                    "id": 2001
                },
                {
                    "id": 2003
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "referenceCopies": [
        {
            "id": 2000
        },
        {
            "id": 2002
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried with recursive template in AngularJS to achieve this but it's not working. Can anyone provide some demo or suggestion to achieve above kind of requirement.
Please let me know if the above description is incomplete or unclear.